# Android source branches

Tags: android, git

We want to build on the froyo android release, but I am having difficulty understanding what the releation is between the different froyo branches.

What is the relation between the Android source branches:

- korg/froyo
- korg/froyo-plus-aosp
- korg/froyo-release

Are some frozen? Which are regularly merged to the other, if at all?

(Bonus points if you can provide the git/repo commands to answer the questions. :) )

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of their [release management process described here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/303ce670483114fc):

> We have a master branch internally, which is where the longest-term work happens.
>   All changes made inside Google and all AOSP contributions end up in that master branch, i.e. it's the **downstream-most branch** as far as Google is concerned, and **typically
>   the least stable one too**.
>
> At some points in development, there's a need to stabilize for one series of releases while making potentially destabilizing changes for later releases.
>   At that point we branch from our internal master branch into a named branch (e.g. `gingerbread`).
>   The named branch is always created months in advance of the first official release from
>   that release family.

(here: `korg/froyo`)

> Along with that named branch, we create a matching release branch that we build from changes done in the named branch (i.e. `gingerbread-release` to match the `gingerbread` branch).
>   **That's the branch that official releases come from** (SDK images, system images for
>   Nexus phones).

(here: `korg/froyo-release`)

> When the source code for a given release is ready to be released, we open-source the open-sourceable part of the release branch, the matching state of the named branch, and we merge the named branch into the AOSP master branch.
>   The AOSP master branch contains the merged sum of all the available AOSP changes.
>
> At the platform level, all projects are branched for all releases, even when we don't anticipate the need to make changes in all projects. It's simpler that way.